# INSERT in Supertype/Subtype tables using PHP/MYSQL (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, triggers, subtype

I have this schema.
[image]

My employees and customers share the same users table. A `user` can be either an `employee` or a `customer`.

How do I INSERT into a user and also make sure to insert in the right (subtype) table which in this case can be employees or customers?

1. Implement logic in PHP? like (for example inserting an employee record): Insert values into users; Check the user_type; If `user_type = emp` then insert the specific values into `employees` table;
2. Use MYSQL triggers, stored procedures? (I am not very familiar with them)

What about when my `employees` could also have subtypes associated to them and need extra fields in different tables (employee_types: sales, acquisitions, managers, etc)?

Comment: @mdamia I used to place everything in the application logic hut somehow I have a feeling that for a bigger and more complex project I'll have issues. Any other way?

Comment: I would recommend, Laravel Docs to get you started.

Comment: @mdamia It's not Laravel that intrigues me. I more concerned on how to do it? What is the "better" method of doing the Inserts. Or better said, in my case do I put the logic in the application or use MYSQLs trigger/stored procedures to achieve the right insert.

Comment: You are already familiar with Logic in the application. so why not go that route, you will spend less time developing the app than if you were to learn MYSQLs trigger/stored procedures. The developers community opinion is divided and would argue one over the other.